# SQL insert multiple NOW() working randomly

Tags: mysql

I have about 40 lines of the following statement

```
INSERT INTO `maindb`.`table` (`a_id`, `b_id`, `c_id`, `time_1`, `time_2`, `time_3`, `time_4`, `p`) VALUES (NULL, '1',3, NOW()+3907, NOW()+4192, NOW()+4291, NOW()+7945, '1');
```

and after I've executed them what's actually stored in MySQL table is

[image: SQL Result Sample]

There are multiple 0000-00-00 00:00:00 scattered all over which shouldn't be happening.

I tried the following which didn't work for me:

- insert 1 line at a time,
- use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of NOW(),
- change the insert statement to one long one instead of multiple single insert statements, and
- switch between InnoDB and MyISAM engines, and
- played around with COMPACT vs REDUNDANT and FIXED vs DYNAMIC row formats.

I can space out the inserting of timestamps but in practice the server will receive thousands if not hundreds of thousands of such "insert" or "update" requests a day with the input being NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Hence the manual way of solving this problem would not make it go away completely.

Any help that could potentially solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you can't add just a number to the date like this. use `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)`, i.e. `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2568 second)`

Comment: Can you please explain what you intend by `NOW()+4192` and the other date arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing math with datetime values, which is never a good idea. `timevalue + integer` will give you an integer result:

```
mysql> select now(), now()+4291;
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| now()               | now()+4291            |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2015-01-13 08:40:18 | 20150113088309.000000 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how the addition has turned your date/time string into a "numericized" number. Basically it's doing a straight string->integer conversion by ripping out the `-` and `:` from the string. Those integers then get stuffed into your date/time fields, and since they're **NOT** date/time values, you get the `0000-00-00` error dates

If you want to do "math" with dates and times, you have to use the proper tools:

```
mysql> select now(), now() + interval 4291 second;
+---------------------+------------------------------+
| now()               | now() + interval 4291 second |
+---------------------+------------------------------+
| 2015-01-13 08:41:21 | 2015-01-13 09:52:52          |
+---------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Perfect answer! This solved my problem. Question still is though why did some "cells", if I may, work but the others didn't?

Comment: It's almost correct, except for the "numericized" explanation. According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), function `NOW()` returns a string or a number, depending on the context where it is used. Being used as an operand of an addition, `NOW()` returns a floating point number and no "numericization" is needed any more :-)

Comment: maybe some of them are timestamp fields and others are date fields?

Comment: you were doing math, so some of the addition results would naturally produce invalid fractional time values, e.g. `257583` for 25 hours, 75 minutes, 83 seconds, instead of `+1 day 2 hour 16 minute 23 seconds` or whatever.

Comment: @revvy: it happens that adding different values to the result of `NOW()` sometimes the outcome can be converted back to `DATETIME`, other times it cannot. The example in the answer is one of the invalid values: there is no `08:83:09` hour on the clock today.

Comment: Thanks folks! Sure does make complete sense now.

Answer (score 1):

mysql Now() functions actually gets the current date and time at which the query is been executed so you are bound to get different values but it is going to be in an incremental order